# owlCarousel карусель перенос видимых элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как можно сделать перенос видимых элементов owlCarousel карусель?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал играть с css стилями, но всё безрезультатно.

Код такой

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/owl.carousel.min.css">
<script src="/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="/owl.autoplay.js"></script>


    <ul id="simple" class="owl-carousel" >

            <li class="item col-md-12">
                  <div class="image">
                <a href="#"><img src="/upload/img.jpg" title="Потолок ледяной, дверь скрипучая" alt="Потолок ледяной, дверь скрипучая"  /></a>
                  </div>
               <div class="info"><a href="#">Название</a></div>
            </li>

            <li class="item col-md-12">
                  <div class="image">
                <a href="#"><img src="/upload/img.jpg" title="Потолок ледяной, дверь скрипучая" alt="Потолок ледяной, дверь скрипучая"  /></a>
                  </div>
               <div class="info"><a href="#">Название</a></div>
            </li>

            <li class="item col-md-12">
                  <div class="image">
                <a href="#"><img src="/upload/img.jpg" title="Потолок ледяной, дверь скрипучая" alt="Потолок ледяной, дверь скрипучая"  /></a>
                  </div>
               <div class="info"><a href="#">Название</a></div>
            </li>

            <li class="item col-md-12">
                  <div class="image">
                <a href="#"><img src="/upload/img.jpg" title="Потолок ледяной, дверь скрипучая" alt="Потолок ледяной, дверь скрипучая"  /></a>
                  </div>
               <div class="info"><a href="#">Название</a></div>
            </li>


            </ul>


<script>
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    items:2,
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:2800,
    autoplayHoverPause:true
});
$('.play').on('click',function(){
    owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[2800])
})
$('.stop').on('click',function(){
    owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay')
})

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    aside  #simple {
        margin: 0;
    }

    section #simple {
        margin-left: -5px;
    }

    #simple li {
        list-style: none;
    }

    #simple .image img {
        height: 120px;
    }

   aside #simple .col-md-12 {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    section #simple .col-md-12 {
        padding-right: 0;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: я заметил что вы только со скриншотером хорошо играете ...а надо играть со сниппетом кода здесь ... и почитайте как создать минимальный самодостаточный код .... если по русскому ваши скрины нужны только вам а сюда надо показывать код .... а скрины в фотошопе нужны

Comment: @Павел Варшавский Извините, забыл.

Comment: @Позитивонлайн проще выбрать другое решение со встроенным вертикальным направлением